# Not able to open website in WebView

Tags: android, webview

XML file:

```
     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText"
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/webView"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/goButton"
         android:ems="10"
         android:gravity="left"
         android:hint="Enter a URL"
         android:inputType="textUri" />
         <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webView"
         android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
         </EditText>
```

and Code:

```
    goButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Editable str = edittext.getText();
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.loadUrl(str.toString());
        }

    });
```

I included internet permissions too in manifest file but still not able to open any website in WebView whichever I enter in EditText.

Please to help.

Comment: Post your onCreate() method.

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: Also, please post your AndroidManifest.